# Does the existence of finite moments imply the existence of finite product moment?

Tags: statistics, expected-value

I've been considering Nasim Taleb's writings on the importance of fat tailed distributions. One of the concerns he expresses has to do with whether a finite moment is defined. This motivates my question, but does not need to be incorporated into the answer.

Question: Is the following expression true?
$$\left( \mathbb{E}[X] < \infty \right) \land \left( \mathbb{E}[Y] < \infty \right) \implies \mathbb{E}[XY] < \infty$$

Comment: For X = Y, this would imply that every RV with first moment has nth moment, which is false.

Comment: @HeiniHøgnason I will accept that counterexample as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $X = Y$, this would imply that every RV with first moment has $n$-th moment, which is false.

However, if $X$ and $Y$ have second moments, it can be shown that the product moment $\mathbb{E}\left[XY\right]$ will exist.